# Logging in: Does the interface make sense?

Tags: discussion, openid, user-interface, login

When logging in there are some icons indicating which OpenID provider you use. What are these for? I click on one and it highlights... but does nothing.

I type in my ID (without the myopenid.com suffix) and it doesn't work.
I type in my name and then click the icon and it just clears out the input field.

What are these icons for? I can't find a use for clicking on them and it has confused me for quite a while now.

**Edit:**
After seeing the responses I understand how it works. For some reason I was simply ignoring the smaller icons below the large ones. However, I still think it could be made quite a bit more obvious somehow. The interface is definitely "making me think". Discuss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, when I log in, I click the myopenid icon and type in myopenid username.

[alt text http://cznp.com/images/myopenid.jpg](http://cznp.com/images/myopenid.jpg)

Comment: +1 for the circle and legible mouse text